# Complex spheres in $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Pardon my complete ignorance with complex geometry.  Are the only complex curves of genus 0 in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ given as the zero sets of equations of the form $ax + by + cz$ for some complex numbers $a,b,c$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The curves given by an irreducible homogeneous polynomial of degree 2 are also genus zero. If you allow singularities (and only considering geometric genus), there are others.